# How to link with static library from same dub file

Tags: d, dub

I have a `dub.json` file that looks like:

```
{
    "name": "myProject",

    "configurations":
    [
        {
            "name": "myLib",
            "targetType": "staticLibrary",

            "sourcePaths": ["myLibSrcDir"],
            "importPaths": ["myLibSrcDir"],
            "targetPath": "build",
        },

        {
            "name": "myExe",
            "targetType": "executable",

            "sourcePaths": ["myLibSrcDir"],
            "importPaths": ["myLibSrcDir"],
            "targetPath": "build",

            "libs": ["$PACKAGE_DIR/build/myLib.a"]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I build with `dub --config=myExe` I get the following linker error: `cannot find -l/home/myUser/myProject/build/myLib.a` even if the library is there.

How may I link a static library generated in the same dub file? I think this is a pretty common case (library + test/sample executables), but I couldn't find any samples.

Comment: I think the answer here is to make the lib just be "Lib" and then use a library search path to find it. idk how to do that in dub (I don't use it), but the `lflags` can do it if all else fails - `"lflags":"-L/home/myUser/myProject/build/"`. I *think* that will work for you.

Comment: You could try to make your library a [subpackage](https://dub.pm/package-format-json.html#sub-packages). Would that work in your case?